# Cant connect to my Bluehost SQLDatabase with php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i wrote a php script which should connect me with my database. I also uploaded the files in the public_html section, but it always throws this error :

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FoodHelperSwift/db/public_html.php on line 24

Here is the line : `$this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);`

This is my code :

> **public_html**

```
   var $conn = null;   
   var $result = null;
   public  $dbhost = null;

   public $dbname = null;   
   public  $dbuser = null;    
   public  $dbpass = null;

    function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname) {
        $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
        $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
        $this->dbpass = $dbpassword;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
    }  


    public function openConnection()
    {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);

      echo "YESSSS";
        echo $this->dbhost;
        echo $this->dbuser;
        echo $this->dbpass;
        echo $this->dbname;
        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {

            throw new Exception("Could not connect with database");
            $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
        }
    }

    public function closeConnection()
    {
        if ($this->conn != null)
        {
            $this->conn->close();
        }
    }

}
```

and

> **register user**

:

```
    require("../db/public_html.php");    
    $dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbname = "xxxxxxxx";  
    $dbuser = "xxxxxxxxx";    
    $dbpassword = "xxxxxxx";    

$returnValue = array();

if(empty($_REQUEST["userEmail"]) || empty($_REQUEST["userPassword"]) 

        || empty($_REQUEST["userFirstName"])

        || empty($_REQUEST["userLastName"]))
{
    $returnValue["status"]="400";

    $returnValue["message"]="Missing required information";

    echo json_encode($returnValue);

    return;
}

$userEmail = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userEmail"]);    
$userPassword = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userPassword"]);    
$userFirstName = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userFirstName"]);    
$userLastName = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userLastName"]);    
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);    
$secured_password = sha1($userPassword . $salt);    
$dao = new MySQLDAO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);    
$dao->openConnection();
```

The password etc. is right and i also tried localhost, but then i got an error that he cant find the file maybe you could help me.

Comment: Update question with problem line broken out - line 24

Comment: Be careful to avoid publishing passwords, please.

Comment: i updated it, take you @dbmitch

Comment: yes olli but im sitting like 3 days on this problem and now its worth for me @Olli Jones

Comment: What is Bluehost - is that a web hosting provider? Adn are you trying to acccess thie db remotely (from home) or from your own website hosted by them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're not following steps provided by your website hosting provider.
Third party hosting solutions usually require you setup your remote IP

From the error message you specified it looks like you're trying to do this from your own home XAMP web service.

> **First - the basics**

:
`localhost` - won't work from home - because that's going to look for your own MySQL database not the hosted db

> **Second - logging in from home (or remotely)**
>   read the docs (always a good idea) [Remote access to Bluehost MySQL](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/89)

**Use the following configuration settings for connecting to your database**

```
Host name = (use the server IP address)
Database name = (cpanelUsername_databaseName)
Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)
Database password = (the password you entered for that database user)
MySQL Connection Port = 3306
TCP or UDP, either is fine.
```

**Allowing a Remote Server to Access Your Database**

Before connecting to MySQL from another computer, the connecting computer must be enabled as an Access Host.

```
Log into cPanel and click the Remote MySQL icon, under Databases.
Type in the connecting IP address, and click the Add Host button.
    Note: You can find and add your IP address directly from this tool. Look for Your IP is: 123.123.12.123 [Add]. Clicking the [Add] link will input your IP into the field box below.
Click Add, and you should now be able to connect remotely to your database.
```

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this, strip your code down to the basics. Make yourself a little `testMyDb.php` file, containing only the minimal stuff.  For example:

```
$dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbuser = "xxxxxxxxx";
$dbpassword = "xxxxxxx";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
  exit();
}
```

Once you have that working, you can proceed to debug your php class and make sure you are setting things up correctly.

Your file named `public_html.php` contains some code that's part of a [php class implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) (for example `__construct()`), but I don't see a `class ClassName {`  line to set up a class definition. It's possible you've copied some fragments of code from somewhere without getting it all.

If your simple test DOESN'T work, check with bluehost's tech support krewe. You may need some special credentials or database name to connect to MySQL from one of their Windows hosts.

If you're using the MySQL server on a bluehost machine, and trying to connect to it from your local machine, that will not work (especially not with `127.0.0.1`). You'll need to configure bluehost to allow remote MySQL connections, and you'll have to use the actual MySQL hostname.